# Access Azure App Service Database from local machine

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-database-postgresql

I'm trying to access Azure App Service Database (Postgress)from a client tool install in my local machine. But still I could not figure-out how to do this.

Can some one please help on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the code and errors you are facing with?

Comment: in terminal, getting this error.

ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'capgo-api-stg-server.mysql.database.azure.com' (8)

Comment: This is not suitable for SO, if you provide the code then it is possible to know much about the error. Provide your effort [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: By observing the error it shows `Unknown MySQL server host` but in the question you says like you are using `Postgresql`. Can you provide some more details of what you are trying to do and the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '******'

This error indicates you are using `mysql` database and not `postgreSQL` and this error can be related to a firewall issue.

Create a firewall rule and add a Public IP address as follows:

- Go to the networking tab and check `Allow public access to this resource through the internet using a public IP address`. Add the Client IP address to the firewall as shown below:

[image]

After creating the firewall rule, try to connect to the server; it should connect successfully.

If you are using VNET instead of public access, create a [Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal) in the VNET and try to connect the server in the VM.

For more information, you can refer to this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/789664/when-trying-to-connect-to-mysql-error-2005-(hy000)) in MS Q/A platform.